# The "keyField" is a required attribute of lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am planning to display records from candidates object in a lightning:datatable. Below is my code.

***Apex class to fetch the candidate records***

```
public class FetchCandidates {

    @Auraenabled
    public static list<Candidate__c>  getCandidates(){
        return [SELECT Id,Lightning1_Srav__Status__c,Lightning1_Srav__Candidate_Email__c,Name FROM Lightning1_Srav__Candidate__c];

    } 

}
```

***JavaScript controller***

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set("v.columns",
                  [
                      {
                          label:'Candidate Name',
                          fieldname:'Name',
                          type:'text'
                      },
                      {
                          label:'Candidate Email',
                          fieldname:'Lightning1_Srav__Candidate_Email__c',
                          type:'text'
                      },
                      {
                          label:'Status',
                          fieldname:'Lightning1_Srav__Status__c',
                          type:'text'
                      }
                 ]);

    var action=component.get("c.getCandidates");

    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var candidates=response.getReturnValue();
    component.set("v.Candidates",candidates);
        console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                  });   

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}

})
```

***CandidatesListItem***

```
<aura:component 
            controller="FetchCandidates" 
            implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride
                        ,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId
                        ,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">

   <aura:attribute name="Candidates" type="Lightning1_Srav__Candidate__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<div style="height: 300px">
<lightning:datatable 

                     keyfield="id"
                     columns="{!v.columns}"
                     data="{!v.Candidates}"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

</div>
```

***Candidates list component***

```
<aura:component 
            implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
            description="This component is to provide list view of candidates">

<lightning:card title="Candidates" footer="">
<aura:set attribute="actions">
    <lightning:button label="new"/>        
    </aura:set>
    <c:CandidatesListitem/>

</lightning:card>
```

Getting error as below and datatable is not rendered. Not sure where this is going wrong. Greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a case error. JavaScript, unlike Apex, is case-sensitive. You should treat all front-end code as being sensitive to case. Your data has the property `"Id"`, not `"id"`, and it looks like some validation code is objecting to the lower case use of the attribute `keyfield`. Use this instead:

```
<lightning:dataTable keyField="Id"
                     columns="{!v.columns}"
                     data="{!v.Candidates}"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

Comment: Hi David thanks for Quick reply,i tried that but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: What behavior did you observe when you made the change? Do you have Debug Mode turned on, and did you ensure all the components were reloaded?

Comment: yes Debug mode is on all components are reloaded. I am logging only Id into console and that is working as expected. But the overall behavior is same, the data table is not rendered and same two messages in console that KEYField should be public or global and its required attribute.

Comment: Got the issue,missed camel case. i wrote it as keyfield, it should be keyField. Marking this as answer